# How to filter data in a Google Sheet so that just the last 20 items per name are included?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I have a google spreadsheet that have more then 1000 rows and it gets updated weekly, each row contain name and one of 3 decisions was made. I want to automate it and have in a separate sheet a table with names and count decisions in numbers and just last 20 for each name.

The desired result would look like
[this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHjDI.png).

> I'm a beginner in JavaScript and any idea or structure on how I can do this using App Script will be very welcome.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). It is unclear why you are requesting an Apps Script solution because this seems doable with plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: I have this formula

=IFERROR(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(RRData!$E:$E,RRData!$E:$E=$A2,RRData!$AE:$AE=$B$1))))

 but it is showing me all the items, I would like too see just last 20 added to the sheet

Comment: Share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data in one tab, and _manually enter_ the desired results in another tab.

Comment: Here is a spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jtadl8nxA1fYcuvHDIG1-gXDS7YDWcdQ7AgBcQDj7Zc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create descending ordinals by agent with this formula in cell `Sheet1!AF1`:

```
=arrayformula( 
  { 
    "Descending ordinal by agent"; 
    iferror( 1 / 
      countifs( 
        E2:E, E2:E, 
        row(E2:E), ">=" & row(E2:E) 
      ) 
    ^ -1 ) 
  } 
)
```

Then **Insert > Sheet** and insert this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
=query( 
  Sheet1!A1:AF, 
  "select E, count(E) 
   where AD is not null 
   and AF <= 20 
   group by E 
   pivot AD", 
  1 
)
```

The formula will give counts by name and decision, only looking at rows where the ordinal is 20 or less. See the new [Solution](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jtadl8nxA1fYcuvHDIG1-gXDS7YDWcdQ7AgBcQDj7Zc/edit#gid=395444920) sheet in your sample spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX({QUERY({Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!AD2:AD, 
 COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!E2:E, ROW(Sheet1!E2:E), ">="&ROW(Sheet1!E2:E))}, 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null and Col3 <= 20 
  group by Col1 pivot Col2 label Col1'Name'"), 
 {"Total"; MMULT(QUERY(QUERY({Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!AD2:AD, 
 COUNTIFS(Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!E2:E, ROW(Sheet1!E2:E), ">="&ROW(Sheet1!E2:E))}, 
 "select count(Col1) where Col1 is not null and Col3 <= 20 group by Col1 
  pivot Col2"), "offset 1", 0)*1, {1;1;1})}})
```

[image]